# Slow connection when I use google products in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, google

So, I use Ubuntu 14.04 and this week, I don't if a problem of connection or o.s, everytime when I use some product of google, like google searcher, gmail, and others my connection is so slow, and just in google products and when I'm using Ubuntu, because in no windows or macOS is fine.

Someone have the same problem?

Comment: Same problem here, but not the same time frame... You asked this on Sep/2014, and I'm have the exact same issue now, on Jul/2015.

Comment: Same occurs to me .. Chrome Web Store is VERY slow .. when I can open it and try to open a page of extension , never And Open